# How can I handle a postback after session expires on an ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, postback, session-timeout

I have a simple ASP.NET 4 site.  I am using Forms Authentication.  I have Session timeout set to 20 minutes.  Also when the user authenticates I set the AuthenticationTicket to expire in 20 minutes.  So normally everything works fine.  If there is more than 20 minutes of inactivity and the user requests a page on the site they are redirected back to the Login page as I would expect.

However, let's say that the user is on a page that contains a form.  Then they wait 25 minutes.  Then they go to submit the form.  Instead of being redirected back to the Login page, the site attempts the postback and I immediately get errors because there is code in the postback that attempts to get information out of Session.

It seems like ASP.NET does not redirect back to Login on postback if the AuthenticationTicket and Session has expired.  How can I handle this?  I hope I don't have to write special code on each page.

ADDED: web.config code

```
<location path="ForgotLogin.aspx">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"></forms>
   </authentication>
   <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Corey

Comment: based on you configurations it seems like you are just loossing you session, somehow the authentication is not lost and when the user posts the form information back to the server the session is lost.
What kind of information are you storing in the session? It has happened to me before that my authentication cookies last longer than my session even when I specify the same amount of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have different timeouts for your session and your authentication cookie. The situation you describe sounds like a session that is timed out with an authentication cookie that is still valid. Look at [this article](http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=74). Especially the section **Do you have a dependency between the user's authentication token and his session?** is for your situation.

Comment: Thanks.  That link you included was very helpful for me.  I was getting Session and Authentication mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to check on each page if you are not explicitly timing the pages out when the session expires.

Make a base class each page inherits Page from.  In the page load event in that class, check for Session.IsNew.  There are a couple other things you can check to be totally sure the session has expired.

Comment: So are you saying that there is something different about a postback as opposed to a regular page request?  When I make a regular page request I don't have to write any special code.  ASP.NET knows that the user's Authentication Ticket has expired so it redirects the user to the home page.  But on a postback it doesn't seem to check the Authentication Ticket.  Is that correct?

Comment: In my experience, yes. They are two different things, unfortunately.

Comment: Remember that the authentication module doesn't know anything about postbacks. For the authentication module a postback is considered like any other request and its handled the same way, so your problem is not at the authentication/authorization level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an authentication issue. You can be authenticated and have the session expire.
They behave independently from each other.

What kind of information are you storing in session?

If this information is for the page I would recomend keeping it in the ViewState or ControlState. If you are keeping information related to the user. I would create an IHttpModule so whenever an Authenticated user calls your website and your session values are null you recreate them before the user hits any page.

Comment: No I am doing it exactly that way.  Like I said - it works just as you would expect when you click on a hyperlink to a page.  If the session has expired then the user is redirected to the login page.  However it seems like ASP.NET doesn't automatically redirect to the login page for you when try a post back after the session has expired.

Comment: can you post some of your web config related to authentication